# Intel Visual Fortran 2013 XE breaks javascript debugger in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2012, fortran, intel

Does anyone know how to stop an install of Visual Fortran XE 2013 from ***breaking*** javascript debugging in Visual Studio 2012?  I reported this to Intel just now as well.

If I simply uninstall the Intel product, thus removing it from Visual Studio, then all functionality returns.  If Visual Fortran is installed, I can only set breakpoints in javascript, and watch variable and other features do not work.  Interestingly, with Visual Fortran installed, Visual Studio labels javascript as Script language; but if uninstalled, then Visual Studio identifies javascript as javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel responded: developers identified the bug in the Fortran debugger expression evaluator and have put in a fix for the October update [2013].

Intel also provided a workaround:  http://software.intel.com/en-us/comment/1750826#comment-1750826

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing it in a VM.  Then use the VM for Fortran and the one on your machine for normal javascript.

Comment: Past versions of Intel Visual Fortran did not break javascript debugging in past versions of Visual Studio.  Using VM as above would lead to inconvenience as I do multi-language programming: Server side C# code invokes Fortran-based dll.

Comment: This has been reported to intel http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/456630.  Guess you'll have to wait for a fix from Intel.

Comment: Yes, see my answer above.